# javascript - How to load two google charts on the same page, different divs

Tags: javascript, html, charts

After a dozen research, still could not solve my problem in showing two graphs on the same page (with `Google Charts`).

I could not figure out what is wrong or what I'm forgetting, if someone can give me some tips or point me what I'm missing, I'll be grateful.

I'm able to show 1 chart, but when I try to show another one, the first dissapears.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

          google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });


    //google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartAtleta);
    //google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartSexo);
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
        drawChartAtleta();
        drawChartSexo();
    });      


    //Grafico Atleta por esporte
    function drawChartAtleta() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Esporte');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Quantidade');
        data.addRows([
          ['Basquete', 30],
          ['Tenis de Mesa', 17]
        ]);

        var options = {
            'title': 'Por Esporte',
            'width': 500,
            'height': 300
        };


        var chart = new google.visualization.CollumChart(document.getElementById('char_atleta'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    //Grafico por Sexo
    function drawChartSexo() {


        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Sexo');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Quantidade');
        data.addRows([
          ['Masculino', 165],
          ['Feminino', 67]
        ]);


        var options = {
            'title': 'Por Sexo',
            'width': 500,
            'height': 300
        };


        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('char_sexo'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }


</script>
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="char_sexo"></div>
            </div>                
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="char_atleta"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please tell me if there's some error in console...

Comment: @TheProHands Presents no mistake, the only thing I knew differently is that drawChartAtleta(); function is not being charged, but I do not see why

Comment: don't know google charts but first thing i wonder is if proper packages are included

Comment: @charliefl Nor me... I'll try to find something, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your script working, you were calling: `google.visualization.CollumChart` instead of `google.visualization.ColumnChart`, always check for javascript errors in the browser developer's console. (f12 usually)

Check google charts documentation for more info about [column charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart)

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="char_sexo"></div>
            </div>                
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="char_atleta"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

          google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });


    //google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartAtleta);
    //google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartSexo);
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
        drawChartAtleta();
        drawChartSexo();
    });      


    //Grafico Atleta por esporte
    function drawChartAtleta() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Esporte');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Quantidade');
        data.addRows([
          ['Basquete', 30],
          ['Tenis de Mesa', 17]
        ]);

        var options = {
            'title': 'Por Esporte',
            'width': 500,
            'height': 300
        };

        //This line was changed.
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('char_atleta'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    //Grafico por Sexo
    function drawChartSexo() {


        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Sexo');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Quantidade');
        data.addRows([
          ['Masculino', 165],
          ['Feminino', 67]
        ]);


        var options = {
            'title': 'Por Sexo',
            'width': 500,
            'height': 300
        };


        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('char_sexo'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Omg, I can't believe with was this, thank you so much for your help, sorry for the silly mistake !! Não acredito que não vi esse erro, muito obrigado !

Comment: Não tem de quê / You're welcome ;) Sometimes silly mistakes happen, just remember to check the developers console ;).